# AutoCompleteTextView doesn't show the text bar

Tags: android, focus, autocompletetextview

I've an AutoCompleteTextView in my Layout, the problem is that although it works perfectly, the "text bar" (I don't know really how it's called "|") is not shown, so it's a bit hard to know where is the focus. Do you know how can I fix it?

```
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/a_addproduct_producto_text" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true" android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal" 
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="17sp"/>
```

Comment: What is the  android:theme in your manifest.xml??

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words.